# Small file to QR Code

Tags: php, google-api, qr-code

I'm basically trying to use Google's QR Code API to create a QR code from an array of bytes. I've tried passing Google's web backend an array of bytes for the 'chl' variable (data for the QR code), but it never seems to like it. I've used Google's PHP example as the basis for my code, but if anyone knows of an alternative way to simply convert an array of bytes into a QR code using Google's API, that's the only goal.

```
<?php
// Create some random text-encoded data for a QR code.
//header('content-type: image/png');    
$url = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chid=' . md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$chd = file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

// Add image type, image size, and data to params.
$qrcode = array(
'cht' => 'qr',
'chs' => '300x300',
'choe' => 'ISO-8859-1',
'chl' => $chd);


// Send the request, and print out the returned bytes.
$context = stream_context_create(
array('http' => array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'content' => http_build_query($qrcode))));
fpassthru(fopen($url, 'r', false, $context));
?>
```

There's the PHP, handling an uploaded file and sending to Google's API via a byte array.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried.

Comment: You could try converting the data to hex.

Comment: Added some PHP of an attempt at sending a byte array from an uploaded file.

Answer (score 1):

The [file](http://www.php.net/file)() function gives an array of strings, split on new lines. I think you just want a string. see [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)()

make sure to

```
echo http_build_query($qrcode);
```

to help you debug.

Comment: `echo http_build_query($qrcode);` This works, and the query looks like it should work just fine. It's sending the file as a byte array exactly as it should, the query looks good. My problem now is that it returns a PNG in raw text without the header changed. When I uncomment the header line to make it a PNG, it doesn't send the request properly.

Comment: what makes you think it doesnt send the request properly?

Comment: Based on the assumption that the echoed request should be accepted by the API and generate a valid barcode, when the header is changed, the API spits out the generic 1-level barcode with no data stored in it.

Comment: Turns out the problem was with sending 0x00 as a part of the byte array. Anyway around this? It's causing the request to think it's the end of the data once it reaches a 0x00. Could I perhaps send it differently to the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can't encode a byte array using the Google Chart Server -- it operates on strings. I think these are valiant attempts at hacking around that but won't work in the end for the reason you've found.

You should just use the encoder in the [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) project locally. It also operates on strings, but, you can actually easily change or inject a call that specifies a byte array directly that way.